# Grow element to fit content, but do not exceed parent

Tags: html, css

I want to have an element - .errorMessages, grows to fit the content (a div with overflow-y: auto to show scrollbar), but do not exceed parent space.

The HTML looks something like this:

```html
<div class="modalBox"> <!-- this changes with window size -->
  <div class="content">
    <table class="vtable" style="width: 350px;">
      <!-- this needs to expand, but not more than the content -->

      ...
    </table>
    <div class="errorMessages flex">
        <!-- this needs to expand, but not more than the content -->
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>an error message</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Close" class="button blue" />
  </div>
</div>
```

How it looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The parent of .errorMessages  is the div .content, right? if the class .flex which is aplied together with .errorMessages is display: flex, it is going to act as you want. Just add .flex {display: flex } to your flex class into your CSS file.

Comment: if .content is flex I can't make .errorMessages to grow only enough to fit content and no more. It grows to fill the rest of the space. If it's not flex - I can't make it shrink.

Answer (score 1):

Give a certain height in rem to your `.content` class. Then give desired heights in percentage to your `.vtable` and `.errorMessages` classess.

```html
<div class="modalBox"> <!-- this changes with window size -->
  <div class="content" style="height: 10rem">
    <div class="vtable" style="width: 350px; height: 50%; overflow-y: auto;">
      <!-- this needs to expand, but not more than the content -->
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>an error message</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="errorMessages flex" style="width: 350px; height: 50%; overflow-y: auto;">
        <!-- this needs to expand, but not more than the content -->
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>an error message</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
          <li>another error message...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Close" class="button blue" />
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, watch out to use proper HTML semantics, for example the table element.

Comment: The content needs to grow and shrink with window size, so it must be in % or vh. The table needs to be fixed size, not %.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using the following simple workaround. I won't accept this as an answer because it doesn't solve the initial problem, and I really want to know if it's possible without javascript.

I'm making the whole .content overflow-y: auto. Then I leave .errorMessages alone and it'll grow to fit content. Since the close button is outside of .content it'll stay on. I set the .content height to calc(100% - var(--close-button-height)).

It's not ideal, but looks ok visually and does the job.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .border {
      border: 1px solid red;
  }

  .modalBox {
      border-color: blue;
      height: 90vh;

  }

  .modalBox .content {
      background-color: #fffeec;
      border-color: #09c900;
      height: calc(100% - 48px);
      /*max-height: calc(100% - 40px);*/
      /*margin-bottom: 40px;*/
      overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .modalBox .content .table {
      border-color: gray;
  }
  .modalBox .errorMessages {
      margin-top: 10px;
      border-color: red;
      background-color: #ffecec;
      height: fit-content;
  }
  .modalBox .errorMessages .errorsContent {
      min-height: 50px;
  }
  .modalBox .buttons {
      background-color: rgba(0, 181, 173, 0.1);
      height: 42px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;

  }

  </style>

<div class="modalBox border">

  <div class="content border">
<div class="table border">
  content<br />
  table<br />
  placeholder<br />
</div>
<div class="errorMessages border">
  <div class="errorsContent">
  <ul>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
    <li>error1</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
<input type="button" value=" Close " />
  </div>
</div>
```